# I can't change the keybinding theme from emacs to default in gnome tweak tool

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, emacs, gnome-tweak-tool

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 Gnome Shell. I have changed the keybinding theme from Default to emacs using Gnome Tweak Tool. For some reason I can't change it back to default. Has anyone encountered  this issue before, and does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by reinstalling Gnome Tweak Tool and restarting Gnome Shell.

Answer (score 1):

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme
```